# Keycloak Gatekeeper failing with session not found error while securing a application

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, amazon-eks, openid-provider, keycloak-gatekeeper

I am trying to secure my Angular web application deployed in [EKS](https://aws.amazon.com/eks/). I am trying to use the Keycloak gatekeeper for securing my app.

But when I do so, requests are hitting to the gatekeeper pod instead of giving me a login screen. I get an error as below:

```
 1.6945349015849838e+09  error   no session found in request, redirecting for authorization      {"error": "authentication session not found"}
    1.6945349015850434e+09  info    client request  {"latency": 0.000098136, "status": 307, "bytes": 95, "client_ip": "10.216.16.169:1792", "method": "GET", "path": "/"}
```

Below is my deployment configuration:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: cnap-ui-admin-dev
  labels:
    app: cnap-ui-admin-dev
    tier: frontend
spec:
  replicas: 1    # Number of replicas of back-end application to be deployed
  selector:
    matchLabels: # backend application pod labels should match these
      app: cnap-ui-admin-dev
      tier: frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels: # Must macth 'Service' and 'Deployment' labels
        app: cnap-ui-admin-dev
        tier: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: cnap-ui-admin
        image: xxxx-ui:latest # docker image of backend applicatio
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 4200
      - name: gatekeeper
        #image: carlosedp/keycloak-gatekeeper:latest
        image: carlosedp/keycloak-gatekeeper:latest
        args:
        - --config=/etc/keycloak-gatekeeper.conf
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
          name: service
        volumeMounts:
        - name: gatekeeper-config
          mountPath: /etc/keycloak-gatekeeper.conf
          subPath: keycloak-gatekeeper.conf
        - name: gatekeeper-files
          mountPath: /html
      volumes:
      - name : gatekeeper-config
        configMap:
          name: gatekeeper-config
      - name : gatekeeper-files
        configMap:
          name: gatekeeper-files
```

The gatekeeper configuration goes as below.

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  keycloak-gatekeeper.conf: |
    # is the url for retrieve the OpenID configuration - normally the <server>/auth/realms/<realm_name>
    discovery-url: https://keycloak.xxx.com/realms/clientrealm
    http-only-cookie: false
    # skip tls verify
    skip-openid-provider-tls-verify: true
    # the client id for the 'client' application
    client-id: login-app
    checkLoginIframe: false
    # the secret associated to the 'client' application
    client-secret: xfPiqMfka5nhcSwkW1uAA2D42cazrY0a
    # the interface definition you wish the proxy to listen, all interfaces is specified as ':<port>', unix sockets as unix://<REL_PATH>|</ABS PATH>
    listen: :3000
    # whether to enable refresh tokens
    enable-refresh-tokens: true
    enable-logging: true
    # the location of a certificate you wish the proxy to use for TLS support
    # tls-cert:
    # the location of a private key for TLS
    # tls-private-key:
    # the redirection url, essentially the site url, note: /oauth/callback is added at the end
    redirection-url: https://app.xxx.com
    secure-cookie: false
    enable-session-cookies: true
    # the encryption key used to encode the session state
    encryption-key: hwvvLHSuUtsxahm2NpAaLJqUGgt7sIjH
    # the upstream endpoint which we should proxy request
    upstream-url: http://127.0.0.1:4200/
    forbidden-page: /html/access-forbidden.html
    resources:
    - uri: /*
      groups:
```

I am following the article [link](https://carlosedp.medium.com/adding-authentication-to-your-kubernetes-front-end-applications-with-keycloak-6571097be090) for the blog. I am using version 20 of Keycloak. And I am avoiding any code change to the frontend application.